# Flask API doesn't recognize folder input

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I'm working with flask on an app that receive an audio file and transcribe it. As long as I pass a single file everything is working fine, I'm now trying to adapt the code in order to pass a folder and start the jobs for every file in it, but for some reasons it is not working, as it only starts the job for the first file in the folder and then in stops working.

That's the html of the app (part of):

```
 <h5 class="mt-5">Select the source type</h5>
        <div class="row mt-3">
            <div class="col">
                <label for="source_type" class="form-label">Select source type:</label>
                <select class="form-select" id="source_type">
                    <option value="file">File</option>
                    <option value="folder">Folder</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of file/folder selector -->

        <!-- Form for loading file or folder -->
        <form id="upload_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="row mt-3">
                <div class="col">
                    <label id="upload_label" for="upload_input" class="form-label">Upload a file:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="file" name="file" id="upload_input">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-2">
                <div class="col-9">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="Upload">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

       <!-- end of form -->


       <!-- some other stuff -->

      <!-- script JS -->
     <script>
    document.getElementById('source_type').addEventListener('change', function() {
        var selected_value = this.value;
        var upload_label = document.getElementById('upload_label');
        var upload_input = document.getElementById('upload_input');

        if (selected_value === 'folder') {
            upload_label.innerText = 'Select a folder:';
            upload_input.setAttribute('webkitdirectory', ''); // Aggiungi attributo per selezionare una cartella
            upload_input.setAttribute('multiple', 'true'); // Aggiungi l'attributo multiple se presente
        } else {
            upload_label.innerText = 'Upload a file:';
            upload_input.removeAttribute('webkitdirectory'); // Rimuovi l'attributo per selezionare una cartella
            upload_input.removeAttribute('multiple'); // Rimuovi l'attributo multiple se presente
        }
    });
</script>
```

That's the code for starting the job:

```
@app.route('/transcriber', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def transcriber():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('jobs_transcriber.html', queued_jobs=jm.queued_jobs, running_jobs=jm.running_jobs,
                               completed_jobs=jm.completed_jobs, max_running_jobs=jm.max_running_jobs,
                               allowed_files=app.config['ALLOWED_FILES_TRANSCRIBER'])
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files and 'folder' not in request.form:
            flash('Missing file or folder part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        
        # If a folder is provided
        folder = request.form.get('folder')
        if folder:
            print('folder')
            input_files = list()
            files_in_folder = os.listdir(folder)
            for filename in files_in_folder:
                print(filename)
                file_path = os.path.join(folder, filename)
                if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                    if not is_allowed_file(app.config['ALLOWED_FILES_TRANSCRIBER'], filename):
                        flash(f'File {filename} is not an allowed file type')
                        continue
                    input_files.append(file_path)
            jm.create_job_transcriber(input_files)
            return redirect(request.url)

        # If a file is provided
        file = request.files['file']
        print('ciaoooooooooo')
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('Missing file name')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if not is_allowed_file(app.config['ALLOWED_FILES_TRANSCRIBER'], file.filename):
            flash(f'File {file.filename} is not an allowed file type')
            return redirect(request.url)
        jm.create_job_transcriber(file)
        return redirect(request.url)
```

The problem is that it never enters the if folder part, going straight to the file part (in fact it prints ('ciaooooooooo') and I don't understand why

If I try to add a `print(request.form)` at the beginning, the result is `ImmutableMultiDict([])`

Comment: Hello,Are you sure you have the folder « templates » that contain your html files in the same directory that the view.py file ?

Comment: if with view.py you mean the file where I have the code with the function `def transcriber`, then yes. In fact the code is working fine with single file, as well as with the upload of a folder. The problem is that it only runs (correctly) on the first file of the folder

Comment: There are too many problems in your code 
first you're checking `folder` key `request.form` there's no field in your form which holds value for that key. Instead of checking for folder & file separately you can write single code which will get file as a list even if it's single file it will do same task for both

Comment: for rg. you can use `request.files.getlist('file')` to get list of files and then rest of your code. In `os.listdir` you've to provide folder name which exists on your server else it will raise `FileNotFoundError` exception. If you want to match same directory of uploaded folder you can split path & then create that path & store rest of files in it.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari yes I've already implemented that and it works! thanks anyway for the answer